# What is the difference between 'localhost:3000/2' and 'localhost:3000' ? the socket.on() can not be executed

Tags: socket.io

**I can successufully execute this:**

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');`
`socket.on('',...)`

**But I can't execute this although the Chrome DevTools(->Network->WS) has data**

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/2');`
`socket.on('',...)`

Can someone please explain the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

3000 is a port number to which your service is served. There is no port 3000/2. Please refer to this for the port number ranges: https://www.utilizewindows.com/list-of-common-network-port-numbers/

Comment: i see what you mean, but  if this didn't work, why did the Chrome DevTools(->Network->WS) have data?